# Welcome to my Island

Tags: word, pattern

I just bought my own island-country the other day, and, as ruler of my new land, I've decided to be a major dingus. I'm not gonna follow other nations in the world like some subservient lemming and use internationally accepted road signs, I'm gonna make up my own, but I need help.

I've set up a brainstorming contest for people to come up with my new road signs. The winner gets **1 free day*** on my island.

I need the following:

- I need a symbol that will show drivers that they need to come to a stop because another car might be coming.
- In some stretches a curve will be ahead, so I think there should be a sign that tells drivers to slow down.
- When really extreme road conditions are present there should be a ***huge warning!***
- Do you think I need a special sign showing upcoming intersections?
- I think that backwoods roads (there'll be a few of those) should have some special designation.
- I'll allow rolling stops at some intersections; I'll need a special symbol for that.
- Feel free to mention anything pertinent that I've left out…

<sub>*Not Included:</sub>
 - <sub>Taxes</sub>
 - <sub>Airfare</sub>
 - <sub>Food and Drink</sub>
 - <sub>Balance of Two-Week Minimum Stay</sub>
 - <sub>Sand Retrieval Service (No sand may be removed from the Island)</sub>

Comment: Isn't this [tag:lateral-thinking] since the goal of the puzzle isn't stated?

Comment: @NH. A puzzle where the goal isn't stated would be an [tag:enigmatic-puzzle]. A [tag:lateral-thinking] puzzle, on the other hand, states the goal of the puzzle but requires creative reasoning to arrive at said goal.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Each of the road signs represents

> A punctuation mark present in its own description.

I need a symbol that will show drivers that they need to come to a stop because another car might be coming.

> The period tells the reader to briefly pause reading because another sentence might be coming.

In some stretches a curve will be ahead, so I think there should be a sign that tells drivers to slow down.

> The comma tells the reader to slow down a little bit in reading.

When really extreme road conditions are present there should be a huge warning!

> The exclamation point is a huge warning.

Do you think I need a special sign showing upcoming intersections?

> The question mark shows the upcoming "intersections." The different roads in the intersection are the different possible answers to the question.

I think that backwoods roads (there'll be a few of those) should have some special designation.

> Parentheses are "backwoods roads," i.e. not part of the main sentence.

I'll allow rolling stops at some intersections; I'll need a special symbol for that.

> A semicolon is not quite a period, and is considered a "rolling stop."

Feel free to mention anything pertinent that I've left out…

> Ellipses indicate that a list is incomplete.

Comment: How would anyone with a brain, and no access to Google, ever come up with this?

Comment: Rot13: va oevgvfu ratyvfu n crevbq vf pnyyrq n shyy fgbc. (link for ease: https://www.rot13.com/ )

Comment: Raise your hand if you have no access to Google.

Comment: Also of note, (rot13) rnpu ohyyrg pbagnvaf vg'f vagraqrq flzoby

Comment: @CDspace I already said that in the first spoiler.

Comment: @Riley So you did. I must have missed that. In any case, well done!

Comment: @Zephyr, I didn't need to Google anything. What tipped me off was when the parallelism was suddenly broken: the fourth bullet is phrased as a question.

Answer (score 4):

Riley's answer is great, but I wanted to further clarify one point, and add one that Riley missed:

When really extreme road conditions are present there should be a huge warning!

> Exclamation points are for **extreme** emotions (in the road analogy, those equate to extreme road conditions).

*Not Included:

> An asterisk points to things that are *not included* in the main text.